# Как объединить в одно регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match('|<section>(.*?)</section>|Uis', $html, $out);
preg_match('|<img src="(.*?)">|Uis',$out[1],$img);
preg_match('|<h1 class="newsbody">(.*?)</h1>|Uis',$out[1],$h1);
preg_match('|<div class="newsbody-text">(.*?)<br>|Uis',$out[1],$body);
```

Comment: Т.е. по факту вам нужен src из _первого_ img, текст из первого h1 и первого <div> встретившихся в блоке <section> ? А что если будет два img ?

Comment: да есть текст, думал можно как то в 1-й элемент массива получить изображение во 2-й h1  в 3-й body Все это находится в секции

Comment: Если они идут в заранее известной последовательности - то легко. Если их последовательность может меняться, то можно, но сложнее , более медленный и нужен preg_match_all и соответственно лишняя вложенность массива. Я сейчас второй вариант придумываю. Потом тогда еще первый набросаю, если он актуален.

Comment: последовательность та же сначала section внутри Img потом h1 и текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если последовательность внутренних элементов всегда одна и та же, то так:

```
preg_match('|<section>.*?<img src="(.*?)">.*?<h1 class="newsbody">(.*?)<\/h1>.*?<div class="newsbody-text">(.*?)<br>.*?<\/section>|Uis', $html, $out);
```

В массиве $out на выходе в 0 элементе вся строка, в элементах 1,2,3 искомые подстроки